# Auto Transform into New Data - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row, transpose

I am a newbie in python, I search in StackOverflow for my case but I couldn't find the technical answer. I have a big number of BS row.

my problem like this, I have a `dataframe`:

```
df
BS          N
BS1 - BS5   1
BS2 - BS7   2
BS1 - BS9   2
BS9 - BS1   1
```

I want to make new data automatically. My expected result like this:

```
New_BS  BS1 - BS5   BS2 - BS7   BS1 - BS9   BS9 - BS1   Total
BS1-2       1                       2                     3
BS2-3       1           2           2                     5
BS3-4       1           2           2                     5
BS4-5       1           2           2                     5
BS5-6                   2           2                     4
BS6-7                   2           2                     4
BS7-8                               2                     2
BS8-9                               2                     2
BS9-8                                            1        1
BS8-7                                            1        1
BS7-6                                            1        1
BS6-5                                            1        1
BS5-4                                            1        1
BS4-3                                            1        1
BS3-2                                            1        1
BS2-1                                            1        1
```

thank you in advance for helping me

Comment: It is not clear at all to me how you got those rows. What is the difference from `BS7-8`  and `BS7-5` e.g.?

Comment: this data about how many people moving from bus stop to bus stop (BS)... BS7-8 mean from bus stop 7 to 8. BS7-5 mean someone from BS7 go to BS 5.

Comment: Is the data in `BS` always the same format?  Is the stops always from 1 to 9?  This maybe impossible without knowing how to iterate through the Bus Stops.  For example, how would you know that going from `BS9 - BS1` involves `BS9->BS7->BS5->BS4` when `BS1 - BS9` goes in sequential order?

Comment: @BillArmstrong , BS1-9 means someone is moving from BS1 to BS 9, but the bus will stop at every BUS stop such as BS2, BS3, BS4, BS5, BS6, BS7 and BS8. in this case I want to know whether someone moving from BS1 to BS9 passes every stop bus.

Comment: What about from `BS9 - BS1`?  This doesn't seem to follow that same pattern.

Comment: @BillArmstrong forgive me,, I edited..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - it's a total hack - but it was fun...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df_flat = pd.DataFrame({"BS": ['BS1 - BS5', 'BS2 - BS7', 'BS1 - BS9', 'BS9 - BS1'],
                   "N" : [1, 2, 2, 1]})

df = df.pivot(columns='BS',
              values='N')

df_flat = df_flat.pivot_table(
              columns='BS',
              values='N')

for column_name, column in zip(list(df), df):
    if int(column[2:3]) < int(column[8:9]):
        for stop in range(int(column[2:3]), int(column[8:9])):
            index = "BS" + str(stop) + "-" + str(stop + 1)
            if index not in list(df.index.values):
                df.loc[index] = np.nan
            df.loc[index, column] = df_flat.loc['N', column]
    else:
        for stop in range(int(column[2:3]), int(column[8:9]), -1):
            index = "BS" + str(stop) + "-" + str(stop - 1)
            if index not in list(df.index.values):
                df.loc[index] = np.nan
            df.loc[index, column] = df_flat.loc['N', column]

df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)

df = df.iloc[len(list(df_flat)):]

print(df.fillna(''))
```

#### Output

```
$ python bus.py
BS    BS1 - BS5 BS1 - BS9 BS2 - BS7 BS9 - BS1  Total
BS1-2         1         2                        3.0
BS2-3         1         2         2              5.0
BS3-4         1         2         2              5.0
BS4-5         1         2         2              5.0
BS5-6                   2         2              4.0
BS6-7                   2         2              4.0
BS7-8                   2                        2.0
BS8-9                   2                        2.0
BS9-8                                       1    1.0
BS8-7                                       1    1.0
BS7-6                                       1    1.0
BS6-5                                       1    1.0
BS5-4                                       1    1.0
BS4-3                                       1    1.0
BS3-2                                       1    1.0
BS2-1                                       1    1.0
```

There are about a 1,000 ways to improve on this - but its an ok start...

Note that the slicing is a very significant constraint on the data set - - You'll have to really rework this to make it dynamic.

Comment: excellent way,,, thank you in advance.. How about if my data `BS  N1 N2 N3`?

Comment: You will have to add another iterative for each level based on the above code - but there are likely better ways to implement with a better defined workspace.

Comment: thank you so much for the idea,,, big insight for me